# How do requestLocationUpdates parameters save power? and why aren't measures available?

Tags: android, gps

I've read [this informative page](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/)! and think that it provides the necessary background.

I'm looking to save some power on the Locations Service, but do not want to give up too much data (being the coordinates being broadcast from the GPS).

requestLocationUpdates allows the minTime parameter which seems apparent in its function. However, the minDistance is a confusing parameter. To me, it seems that the device is receiving the NMEA stream, parsing the stream to workable doubles, storing some numbers, and computing a distance from the prior reading... all in the background. So, how does the minDistance really save any power?

In addition, the debug information (see above link) indicates that a distance is being broadcast to the listener, but why isn't available to me? I have not tried to understand why Location.distanceBetween(some points) doesn't work for me, and I prefer my own calculations anyway, but might have chosen to use the value broadcast by the device if it were available.

Thanks for any insights as I try to find a sweet spot in saving power vs. saving precision on my path (pun).

Answer (score 0):

minDistance saves power by not calling your app.  SO lets say it takes 10 units of power to process the data from the satellite.  Lets say your app takes 1 unit of power each time a new location is sent to it.  So if you have a minimum distance of 0, the entire process takes 11 units.  If you have a minimum distance large enough you aren't called, it only takes 10.  Its a small but non-zero savings that can add up over time.

As for distanceBetween-  it works perfectly as far as I can tell.  If you're using your own calculations you're probably wrong-  are you taking into account the fact that the distance between 2 lines of longitude is a function of the latitude and not constant?  Probably not.

Comment: Nope, I'm not making the distance between the two longitudinal points a function of the latitude. I've considered doing so, but have not. Is java doing this for me in distanceBetween?

Comment: Too, can I access the 'distance' value picked up the debug information in the link above?

Comment: Yes, it is.  And without it your results are wrong-  how wrong depends on how close to a pole you are.

Comment: Right, how close you are to the pole.... And whether you are traveling at supersonic speeds. I appreciate you pointing out the "degree of wrongness", but the difference is actually very small when you are taking measurements every second. I am still interested in any insights anyone has to the 2 questions.

Comment: Its actually not insignificant at all over the difference of even a few miles.  The difference in distance at the equator vs at 40degrees latitude is almost 25%